AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv'
I would like to export cleaned dataset into CSV. I get the error message:

AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In\[57\], line 20
18 # Save the cleaned and updated dataset to a CSV file
19 output_file_path = r'D:\\Users\\Desktop\\ProjektAnalitiks\\data\\02_Interim\\dropped_rows_columns.csv'
\---\> 20 data_cleaned_dropped.to_csv(output_file_path, index=False)
22 print(f"Dataset saved to {output_file_path}")

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv'

Portion of code:
# Columns to drop based on the missing percentage

columns_to_drop = \[
'Nazwa',
'Czas ostatniej modyfikacji',
'Jeżeli pominięto branżę, na której się znasz dopisz ją:',
'Jeżeli jest obszar, na którym się znasz i chcesz go wykorzystać, dopisz go:',
'Masz jakiś pomysł na projekt data? Napisz nam o tym. Jeżeli to nie ten moment, pozostaw puste pole.'
\]

# Dropping the specified columns from the cleaned dataset

data_cleaned_dropped = data_cleaned.drop(columns=columns_to_drop)

# Checking the size of the cleaned dataset after dropping columns

dataset_size = data_cleaned_dropped.shape

# Display the size of the cleaned dataset

print("Number of rows:", dataset_size\[0\])
print("Number of columns:", dataset_size\[1\])

# Display the first few rows of the updated dataset to confirm the columns are dropped

print(data_cleaned_dropped.head())

# Checking the size of the original dataset

original_dataset_size = data.shape

# Display the size of the original dataset

print("Number of rows:", original_dataset_size\[0\])
print("Number of columns:", original_dataset_size\[1\])

# Checking the size of the original dataset

data_cleaned_dropped = data_cleaned_dropped.shape

# Display the size of the original dataset

print("New number of rows:", data_cleaned_dropped\[0\])
print("New number of columns:", data_cleaned_dropped\[1\])

# Save the cleaned and updated dataset to a CSV file

output_file_path = r'D:\\Users\\Desktop\\ProjektAnalitiks\\data\\02_Interim\\dropped_rows_columns.csv'
data_cleaned_dropped.to_csv(output_file_path, index=False)

print(f"Dataset saved to {output_file_path}")

Exporting cleaned dataset to CSV.


The error says that data_cleaned_dropped is a tuple. Looking back, we see data_cleaned_dropped = data_cleaned_dropped.shape. There's your problem.

You reassigned data_cleaned_dropped = data_cleaned_dropped.shape, which means data_cleaned_dropped is no longer the original dataframe, it is only shape, which is a tuple.

The error message 'tuple' object has no attribute 'to_csv' refers to the line
data_cleaned_dropped.to_csv(output_file_path, index=False)

Tracebacks don't lie. At this point of execution, data_cleaned_dropped is a tuple. That's strange, because it was clearly a DataFrame when it was first assigned. To debug, search that variable name and see if it was reassigned sometime before the error occurred. Sure enough,
data_cleaned_dropped = data_cleaned_dropped.shape

It's now the shape tuple. That line doesn't do anything useful. If you need the shape at some point, it's still on the dataframe. Just remove it.
